# How to automate numerous iterations/combinations for a function's arguments in R?

Tags: r, function, automation, arguments, iteration

I am somewhat new to R and I am currently trying to automate all possible iterations for a function's arguments in R. What I mean by this is say we have a function with five arguments that can either be `TRUE` or `FALSE`. I want to run every possible combination of these arguments and dump them all to several different variables.

Given the number of arguments and their binary nature (10 possible arguments, pick 5), this creates 252 possible argument combinations for the function. Is there any way to automate this process? Or am I stuck generating all 252 possible combinations in code lines? I'm using the auto.arima function, and want to test all possible combinations of `lambda`, `allowmean`, `allowdrift`, `seasonal`, and `stationary`. Here's the function:

```
ARIMA1<-auto.arima(x, d=NA, D=NA, max.p=5, max.q=5,
     max.P=2, max.Q=2, max.order=5, max.d=2, max.D=1, 
     start.p=2, start.q=2, start.P=1, start.Q=1, 
     stationary=FALSE, seasonal=TRUE,
     ic=c("aicc", "aic", "bic"), stepwise=TRUE, trace=FALSE,
     approximation=(length(x)>100 | frequency(x)>12), xreg=NULL,
     test=c("kpss","adf","pp"), seasonal.test=c("ocsb","ch"),
     allowdrift=TRUE, allowmean=TRUE, lambda=NULL, biasadj=FALSE,
     parallel=FALSE, num.cores=2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method to do this would be to use `expand.grid` to construct a data.frame with all possible combinations, then loop through the rows of this data.frame and fill in the values.

Here's an example:

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 2:6
z <- c(1,3)
aa <- letters[7:10]
w <- c(FALSE, TRUE)

myInputs <- expand.grid(x, y, z, aa, w)

for(i in seq_len(nrow(myInputs))) {
  print(myInputs[i, 1] + myInputs[i, 2] + myInputs[i, 3])
}
```

You can instead use these inputs to feed any function that you want.

Since `expand.grid` outputs a data.frame, there is no problem in mixing up vector types (like numeric, logical, character).

However, if you are inputting character vectors, and you want them to remain character (rather than being converted into factor variables, make sure to include the stringsAsFactors=FALSE argument.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out with my data. Is it possible to store logical values (like `TRUE` or `FALSE`) in the data frame?

Comment: It sure is. I'll add that just for the sake of completeness.